# How to find the intersection point in rootlocus diagram?

Tags: control, control-system, homework, root-locus

**Question:**

---

> Sketch the root locus for the open loop transfer function of a unity feedback control sytem given below and determine the value of K for \$\xi=0.5\$
>
> \$G(s)=\frac{K}{s(s+1)(s+3)}\$

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have drawn the root locus diagram like this

[image]

Now i tried all possible way to get the intersection point of rootlocus diagram with the 60 degree line.If i get that point i can easily find the value of K for \$\xi=0.5\$.

Is is possible to find that point without any software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic equation is:

$$s(s+1)(s+3)=-K$$

Hence, plug in any point on the locus, and that will give the corresponding value of K.

It appears that your selected point on the locus is approximately: \$s=-0.4+j0.7\$, which will give \$K\approx 1.8\$

For an accurate answer to this particular problem (\$\small \zeta=0.5\$), write the CE as: $$s(s+1)(s+3)+K= (s+\alpha)(s^2+\omega _n s+ \omega_n^2)$$

solve for \$\alpha\$ and \$\omega_n\$, and hence find K. Thus:

$$ s^3+(\alpha +\omega_n)s^2+(\alpha\omega_n+\omega_n^2)s+\alpha\omega_n^2=s^3 +4s^2+3s+K$$
Giving \$\small K=1.83\$.

Systems higher than 3rd order will need a root solver.

But this approach begs the question, why bother to sketch the root locus in the first place?

Comment: I want that \$"point"\$ to plug into that equation.I think you did't get what i am asking...i am asking that point coordinates where \$\xi\$ becomes 0.5

Comment: how did you get that point coordinates please tell me?thats my doubt only

Comment: From the graph, assuming the axes are to the same scale.

Comment: Really i am not getting what you are trying to say sir

Comment: The point on the graph is at (-0.4, 0.7) if the 'y-axis' scale is the same as the 'x-axis' scale.

Comment: "The point on the graph is at (-0.4, 0.7)"....how did you get this actually? tell me the process to get this?

Comment: I can't say it more plainly, the co-ordinates of the point of intersection of the 60 degree line and the locus are approximately -0.4 on the negative real axis and 0.7 on the imaginary axis. Arctan (0.7/0.4) = 60 degrees.

Comment: Okay i got you how you did that but thats the approximate value you got, i want exact value so i think its not possibe...however answer is  \$S=(-.35,.6)\$ and K=1.66

Comment: It is possible if you let the characteristic be: \$s(s+1)(s+3)+K= (s+\alpha)(s^2+\omega _n s+ \omega_n^2)\$ and solve the resulting quadratic for \$\omega_n\$ and \$\alpha\$. But you're not going to get an exact answer from a hand-drawn graph with a vague scale!

Comment: there is two unknown in that equation,and you got only one equation..i don't see any way to solve that and will give me the result...if you can do it and show me i will accept your answer :-))

Comment: you equation actually should be like this ....\$ s(s+1)(s+3)+K= (s+\alpha)(s^2+2\xi\omega _n s+ \omega_n^2)\$ am i right...i got 1.83 too by solving that equation

Comment: in question they asked to draw rootlocus and then asked to find the value of K... but i think its simple in this way...also i think 1.66 should not be the answer..it should be 1.82 right? your method actually worked ....

Comment: Yes but, as I said in my solution, \$2\zeta\omega_n=\omega_n\$ because \$\zeta =0.5\$

Comment: If they asked to get K from the RL, then doing it a different way is not going to get any marks, even if it's more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

We search a given line for a point that yields a summation of angles (for both zero and pole angles) equal to an odd multiple of \$180^\circ\$. Take a look at the following picture

[image]

The line in which a point that yields a summation of angles equal to an odd multiple of 180 deg is shown as the Green line in the above picture. The angle of this line is \$ \beta = \cos^{-1} (\zeta) \$ and the radius that satisfies the aforementioned condition is searched by a software that we code.  In this example, this is Matlab code that searches for the target point.

```
r=.75;
while r < .76
zeta=.5; 
a=acos(zeta);
x=r*cos(a);
y=r*sin(a);

%poles' angles
p1=0;
Th1=pi-atan( y/x );

p2=-1;
Th2=atan(y/(abs(p2)-x));

p3=-3;
Th3=atan(y/(abs(p3)-x));

angle=-(Th1+Th2+Th3);
fprintf('Th1=%.3f : Th2=%.3f : Th3=%.3f  :  angle=%.3f  : r=%.3f\n', rad2deg(Th1),rad2deg(Th2), rad2deg(Th3),rad2deg(angle),r);

r = r + .00001;
end
```

If you run the code, you notice the following result

```
Th1=120.000 : Th2=46.102 : Th3=13.898  :  angle=-180.000  : r=0.750
```

The aforementioned condition is satisfied if \$\theta_1 = 120^\circ, \theta_2=46.102^\circ \$ and \$\theta_3 = 13.898^\circ\$ which yields a radius \$r=0.75\$. The point \$P\$ is then \$ (r\cos(\beta), r\sin(\beta))\$, or \$P=-0.3750+j0.6495\$. Now, to compute the gain *K*, we substitute *P* in the following formula:

$$
\begin{align}
K &= \frac{1}{|G(s)||H(s)|} \\
  &= |s(s+1)(s+3)| \Big|_{s=P} \\
  &= 1.8281.
\end{align}
$$